# np.linalg.norm and how to deal with machine epsilon

Tags: python, numpy, euclidean-distance, epsilon

I have this fairly simple problem. I want to calculate Euclidean distance with numpy with this code:

```
a= np.array([1,2,3])
b= np.array([2,3,4])

print((np.linalg.norm(a-b))**2)
```

This yields `2.9999999999999996`, However, the answer should be `3`. How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: For that simple problem, you can use `((a-b)**2).sum()` if you are looking for precision. Or `d = a-b; np.einsum('i,i->',d,d)` for performance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use [np.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to compare float values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a round() function

```
a= np.array([1,2,3])
b= np.array([2,3,4])

print((np.linalg.norm(round(a-b))**2))
```

Comment: but I don't really want to round it?

Comment: Im very confused. If you round that number you will get 3. You need to round it to get that number.